# Post "https://***.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/persistentvolumes": dial tcp *****:443: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, persistent, persistent-volumes

I'm getting this error when creating the persistent volume through terraform for EKS.
Created the EBS volume through terraform only.. It successfully created. But when try to create the Persistent volume getting the error

Please check the code below

```
                resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "api-application-pv" {
                  metadata {
                    name            = "api-application-pv"
                  }
                  spec {
                    capacity = {
                      storage = "2Gi"
                    }
                    
                    access_modes    = ["ReadWriteMany"]
                    
                    persistent_volume_source {
                      aws_elastic_block_store {
                        volume_id   = aws_launch_template.default.arn
                              
                      }
                      
                    }
                  }
                }

                resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "api-application-pvc" {
                  metadata {
                    name            = "api-application-pvc"
                  }
                  spec {
                    resources {
                      requests = {
                        storage     = "2Gi"
                      }
                    }
                    access_modes    = ["ReadWriteMany"]
                    storage_class_name = "gp2"
                   volume_name = "${kubernetes_persistent_volume.api-application-pv.metadata.0.name}"
                  }
                  
                  wait_until_bound = false
                  depends_on = [kubernetes_persistent_volume.api-application-pv]
                }
       resource "aws_launch_template" "default" {
                  name_prefix            = "eks-stage-template"
                  description            = "eks-stage-template"
                  update_default_version = true

                  block_device_mappings {
                    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

                    ebs {
                      volume_size           = 50
                      volume_type           = "gp2"
                      delete_on_termination = true
                      encrypted             = true
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: Do you have a `required_providers` block in your code and `kubernetes` provider block? If so, please add that to the question.